# Is there a bgerror hook equivalent for uncaught errors out of the event loop in TCL?

Tags: error-handling, tcl

In Tcl, when an uncaught error occurs in the background in the event loop, the function `bgerror` will be called if one exists (or any function registered via `interp bgerror`).

When an unknown command is encountered, the `unknown` command will be called.

**Is there a similar mechanism for uncaught errors outside of the event loop that make their way to the top level?** The default behavior from `tclsh` is just to print the error on `stderr`, but I would like a specific `proc` to be called instead without having to put the entire code in one big `catch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour, if a Tcl error makes it's way to the top of the main execution path, is to print the `errorInfo` trace to standard error and, if running as a script, exit with a non-zero result code. If you want to override this, you need to either write your own entry code/main loop in C (when you can do anything you want when `Tcl_Eval()` returns `TCL_ERROR`), or wrap your code in a `catch` or `try`. You can use `uplevel #0` within such Tcl code to ensure that the trapping code doesn't appear to be on the stack as seen by the rest of your code.

For example:

```
proc printStackOnError {script} {
    try {
        uplevel "#0" $script
    } on error {msg opt} {
        set stackinfo [dict get $opt -errorinfo]
        # remove last three uninteresting lines; they're just part of this procedure's machinery
        puts stderr [join [lrange [split $stackinfo "\n"] 0 end-3] "\n"]
    }
}
```

Demonstrating (interactively, with Tcl 8.6):

```
% printStackOnError {eval {error foo}}
foo
    while executing
"error foo"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval {error foo}"
```

You're advised to make sure you either print or log the `errorInfo` when an error is trapped at that level.  Otherwise any bugs in your code are going to be unreasonably difficult to fix.